# Ionic 4 No component factory found

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to add custom popup in my app. So i created a page for popup.

I am calling popup in page like this

```
import { RedeemPopupPage } from '../popups/redeem-popup/redeem-popup.page';

  async presentPopover() {
    const popover = await this.popoverController.create({
      component: RedeemPopupPage,
      translucent: true,
      backdropDismiss: false
    });
    return await popover.present();
  }
```

And i am creating a simple page by ionic g page popups/redeem-popup
The file command generating is

```
redeem-popup-routing.module.ts
redeem-popup.module.ts
redeem-popup.page.html
redeem-popup.page.scss
redeem-popup.page.spec.ts
redeem-popup.page.ts
```

But this error is showing `Error: No component factory found for RedeemPopupPage. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?`

And project dont have component file. I am doing something wrong or creating page wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to Add your page to your `app.module.ts`;

For Example:

```
import { YourComponent } from './youcomponent/youcomponent.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    YourComponent      //add it in declarations
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    YourComponent     // also add it to you entryComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```